# Node.js, Express, Mocha, Zombie missing bindings file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, zombie.js

I'm following the *Web Development with Node and Express* tutorial by Ethan Brown published by OReilly.  In the fifth chapter Mocha is used with Zombie to test basic functionality but it isn't working and the following is printed.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/meadowlark/site$ mocha -u tdd -R spec qa/tests-crosspage.js
/vagrant/meadowlark/site/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:91
  throw err
  ^

Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → /vagrant/meadowlark/site/node_modules/contextify/build/contextify.node
 → /vagrant/meadowlark/site/node_modules/contextify/build/Debug/contextify.node
 → /vagrant/meadowlark/site/node_modules/contextify/build/Release/contextify.node
 → /vagrant/meadowlark/site/node_modules/contextify/out/Debug/contextify.node
 → /vagrant/meadowlark/site/node_modules/contextify/Debug/contextify.node
 → /vagrant/meadowlark/site/node_modules/contextify/out/Release/contextify.node
 → /vagrant/meadowlark/site/node_modules/contextify/Release/contextify.node
 → /vagrant/meadowlark/site/node_modules/contextify/build/default/contextify.node
 → /vagrant/meadowlark/site/node_modules/contextify/compiled/6.3.0/linux/x64/contextify.node
    at bindings (/vagrant/meadowlark/site/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:88:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/meadowlark/site/node_modules/contextify/lib/contextify.js:1:96)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/meadowlark/site/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/index.js:17:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/meadowlark/site/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:13:43)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/meadowlark/site/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/resources.js:11:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/meadowlark/site/node_modules/zombie/lib/zombie/index.js:6:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/meadowlark/site/qa/tests-crosspage.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:220:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:217:14)
    at Mocha.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:469:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:404:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:352:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:144:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:467:3
```

Following the advice found in the "Code in the book not working?" section of [github link](https://github.com/EthanRBrown/web-development-with-node-and-express) I've reinstalled all the dependencies using the versions listed in `package.json` in the ch05 folder.  Still having the same problem I decided to implement the next test which works fine.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/meadowlark/site$ mocha -u tdd -R spec qa/tests-unit.js 


  Fortune cookie tests
    ✓ getFortune() should return a fortune


  1 passing (16ms)
```

The next part of the QA chapter covers Grunt which I can't get to work because the same error.  I've cloned Ethan's git repo into a separate directory, reinstalled all the dependencies, ran the server, ran the tests and finally saw the correct Mocha output.

I've tried using `diff` on some my files against Ethan's and haven't found any culprit of the error... just lots of coding style differences and trailing spaces.

Here's a list of the file's and their contents that may be causing the problem.
`tests-crosspages.js`

```
var Browser = require('zombie'),
        assert = require('chai').assert;

var browser;

suite('Cross-Page Tests', function(){

    setup(function(){
        browser = new Browser();
    });

    test('requesting a group rate quote from the hood river tour page ' +
            'should populate the referrer field', function(done){
        var referrer = 'http://localhost:3000/tours/hood-river';
        browser.visit(referrer, function(){
            browser.clickLink('.requestGroupRate', function(){
                assert(browser.field('referrer').value === referrer);
                done();
            });
        });
    });

    test('requesting a group rate from the oregon coast tour page should ' +
            'populate the referrer field', function(done){
        var referrer = 'http://localhost:3000/tours/oregon-coast';
        browser.visit(referrer, function(){
            browser.clickLink('.requestGroupRate', function(){
                assert(browser.field('referrer').value === referrer);
                done();
            });
        });
    });

    test('visiting the "request groupe rate" page directly should result ' +
            'in an empty referrer field', function(done){
        browser.visit('http://localhost:3000/tours/request-group-rate',
                function(){
            assert(browser.field('referrer').value === '');
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

`meadowlark.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var fortune = require('./lib/fortune.js');

var app = express();

// set up handlebars view engine
var handlebars = require('express3-handlebars').create({
    defaultLayout:'main',
    helpers: {
        section: function(name, options){
            if(!this._sections) this._sections = {};
            this._sections[name] = options.fn(this);
            return null;
        }
    }
});
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// set 'showTests' context property if the querystring contains test=1
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.showTests = app.get('env') !== 'production' && 
        req.query.test === '1';
    next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('home');
});
app.get('/about', function(req, res){
    res.render('about', {
        fortune: fortune.getFortune(),
        pageTestScript: '/qa/tests-about.js'
    });
});
app.get('/tours/hood-river', function(req, res){
    res.render('tours/hood-river');
});
app.get('/tours/request-group-rate', function(req, res){
    res.render('tours/request-group-rate');
});
// custom 404 page
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.status(404);
    res.render('404');
});

// custom 500 page
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500);
    res.render('500');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log( 'Express started on http://localhost:' +
        app.get('port') + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.' );
});
```

Comment: I've had a problem with "Could not locate the bindings file" too. So probably problem is with contextify npm module. Try to run `node-gyp rebuild` from project folder. It will creating new binding for native modules as contextify

Comment: @YaroslavTkachenko Thank you for the suggestion.  I'm not stuck at `gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /vagrant/meadowlark/site) while trying to load binding.gyp`.  Presently I'm looking at the documentation for node-gyp and wondering, what did your binding.gyp file looked like?

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/233#issuecomment-222481831